# problem with parsing XML with grails

Tags: xml, grails

I'm developing an application which extracts information about musical events from Last.fm API.
However, for some reason the application is parsing only the first two events from the XML file and I can not figure out why. Any help?

This is the code:

```
def resultList = []

    if(connection.responseCode == 200){
        def xml = connection.content.text
        def lfm = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
        lfm.events.event.each {
            def result = [:]
            result.eventId = it.id as String
            result.eventTitle = lfm.events.event.find { it.'id' == result.eventId }.title as String

            resultList << result

        }
```

Comment: I just realized that the problem might be in the Controller class and not in the XML parsing. It produces the following exception: "Exception occurred when processing request: [POST] /events/event/save - parameters:artist: artist
create: Create". Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you post more code? The controller action and whatever method calls the snippet you posted should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the bug was in the save{} closure of the Controller class. The following is the code with the bug:

```
def save = {
    resultsList.each{
        def eventInstance = new Event(params + it)
        if (eventInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), eventInstance.id])}"
            redirect(action: "show", id: eventInstanceID)
        }
        else {
            render(view: "create", model: [eventInstance: eventInstance])
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem was that I was redirecting the action "show" inside the each{} closure. And for some reason that I'm still not sure, it was throwing an exception after the second iteration of the each{} loop. So all I had to do was to call the redirect method outside the each{} closure, like this:

```
   def save = {
    def resultsList = eventService.lastFmVenues(params.artist)
    def eventInstanceID
    resultsList.each{
        def eventInstance = new Event(params + it)
        if (eventInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), eventInstance.id])}"
            eventInstanceID = eventInstance.id
        }
        else {
            render(view: "create", model: [eventInstance: eventInstance])
        }
    }
    redirect(action: "show", id: eventInstanceID)
}
```

I'm still curious why it was throwing the exception only after the second iteration, but anyway, the problem is solved. Thanks!